# Adding dashes to asp:Label phone field via jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, label

I have asp:Label phone field  bindings from db. What i need to add dashes to make phone format like 999-999-9999 instead of 99999999999. 
I try something like that, but it's doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function ()  
    num = $('#<%=HomePhone.ClientID %>').innerText;
    parts = [num.slice(0,3),num.slice(3,6),num.slice(6,10)];
    fNum = parts[0]+"-"+parts[1]+"-"+parts[2];
    num = fNum;
});
```

Comment: Do it on the server! The clientside is a bad place to do it.

Comment: First of all, your `$(document).ready(function ()` is missing an opening bracket

Comment: I can't do it on the server cos this data uses by many controls, it just needs for displaying, and answer below from timothyclifford is amazing. Anyway thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<p id="textbox">99999999999</p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    var num = $('#textbox').html();
    var parts = [num.slice(0, 3), num.slice(3, 6), num.slice(6)];
    var fNum = parts[0] + "-" +parts[1] + "-" + parts[2];
    $('#textbox').html(fNum);
});​
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/timothyclifford/h9ZCR/

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    num = $('#<%=HomePhone.ClientID %>').text(); // jQuery does not know innerText
    parts = [num.slice(0,3),num.slice(3,6),num.slice(6,10)];
    fNum = parts[0]+"-"+parts[1]+"-"+parts[2];
    //num = fNum; // setting a variable's value does not change value of your text box
    $('#<%=HomePhone.ClientID %>').text(fNum); // set the value using jQuery
});
```